# How can I align an Image in the reportheader with a Textbox in the Body from an RDL(C) report

Tags: c#, report, rdl

I have an Invoice template in which I have an company logo in the Report header (I only want to show this on the first and last page of the invoice)
The report body starts with some text boxes with customer info and our division info.
In the designer all is perfectly aligned but after rendering (to PDF) the logo shifts right and is not aligned anymore.
Body size is smaller than the page size (19 cm vs 21 cm)[image]

Comment: The RDLC file is text in html format.  Open with a text editor and check the font sizes and alignment.

Comment: @jdweng, please elaborate, what influence does the font size of the text in a box have on the positioning of the image. I follow you that a textbox can grow or shrink, but the image moves, the box with the [@DivisionName] stays perfectly aligned with the Tablix under it.